# Function "Position" does not work with space in text function

Tags: postgresql

An example of a function that should return the number of the first character in a substring.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.test(
  IN tstr character varying,
  IN delimiter character)
RETURNS int AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  return position(delimiter in tstr);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Call her:

```
 select dbo.test('11',' ');
```

We get result 1, but there is no space in the substring! How to fix it?
I use PostgreSQL 10.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: Which version of postgres are you using?

Comment: Could you give us more background information? It would be much easier then to help you.

Comment: I use PostgreSQL 10.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, it helped me! strange of course a mistake

Comment: Seems to have been a change in v12, as I am able to reproduce the behavior in v10 and v11, but not v12.  A quick scan through the changelog seems to indicate that commit 9556aa01c69a26ca726d8dda8e395acc7c1e30fc might have caused the behavior change (see also https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BTgmoYioeMyZ61th2mUoRj00Eh1uwTQQMWqZVYKdLx%2BjbYQmw%40mail.gmail.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the underlying reason is, but it's caused by declaring the parameter as `character` (you [shouldn't be using](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29) `char` or `character` anyway).

You can see that if you explicitly call position() with a `character` parameter as well:

```
postgres=# select position(' '::character in '11');
 position
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

Change your function declaration to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.test(
  IN tstr character varying,
  IN delimiter character varying)
...
```

and your example function will work.

---

Note that simple functions like that are much better written as `SQL` functions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbo.test(IN tstr character varying, IN delimiter character varying)
  RETURNS int 
AS
$BODY$
  select position(delimiter in tstr);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql immutable;
```

Comment: Seems to have been a change in v12, as I am able to reproduce OP's behavior in v10 and v11, but not v12.  A quick scan through the changelog seems to indicate that commit 9556aa01c69a26ca726d8dda8e395acc7c1e30fc might have caused the behavior change (see also https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BTgmoYioeMyZ61th2mUoRj00Eh1uwTQQMWqZVYKdLx%2BjbYQmw%40mail.gmail.com)

Comment: @richyen: yes, I noticed that as well. But couldn't find anything in the release notes

Comment: It seems that the issue was fixed in 12 unwittingly.